# How to do exception handling (try/catch) on constructors and final variable on Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, error-handling, constructor

Let's suppose you have a final variable that will be instantiated in the constructor:

```dart
class MyClass {
   MyClass(): person = Person();   

   final Person person;
}
```

But how can I handle exceptions from the constructor of `Person` there? Something like this:

```dart
class MyClass {
   MyClass(): try { person = Person(); } catch { person = nil; }

   final Person? person;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try doing it like this:

```
class MyClass {
  MyClass() {
    try {
      person = Person();
    } catch (e) {
      person = null;
    }
  }
  late final Person? person;
}
```